# laravel 5 ajax authentification

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

I need to create auth from any pages over ajax. If i'm send wrong login and empty pass(or vice versa) - will be return json errors (it's ok). If i'm send wrong login and wrong pass(or right login and path) - will be return redirect.

How to change backend for get response json anyway?

my frontend code js:

```
$("#authform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

html:

```
<form id="authform" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

routes.php:

```
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

Comment: First post your sample code. So that we could help easily...

Comment: added. maybe have example for ajax authentication? i'm didn't found

Comment: In your controller use `response()->json(['data' : 'test']);`. It will send responses to client in json format.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. First try this then we should

```
$('#authform').on('submit',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: $(#authform).attr("action"),
    data: $('#authform').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
return false;
});
```

And have you tried this link [How to create AJAX login with Laravel](http://wsnippets.com/create-ajax-login-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better solution for this problem, but what I did was:

1. Create a new route for loging in 
   `Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@signIn');`
2. In `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` I added two new methods:

   ```
   public function signIn(Request $request) {
       $this->validateLogin($request);

       $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

       if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
           $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

           return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
       }

       $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

       if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
           return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
       }

       if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
           $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
       }

       return $this->sendFailedLoginResponseJSON($request);
   }
   ```

AND

```
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponseJSON(Request $request)
    {
       return response()->json(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()], 422);
    }
```

It's basically the same as the login method from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, except for the last line, the login method uses

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

which sends back a redirect with the error.

If you want both ajax and non-ajax, you can do

```
        if($request->ajax()){
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponseJSON($request);
        }
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
```

in the new sign in method.